# How to deal with List properties

Tags: c#

The list doesn't add anything when the method is called, it throws an exception.
How should it be done and is it possible to do without writing this:

```
public List<string> Mark = new List<string>();
```

I've done like this and this gives an exception

```
public class Student
{
    protected List<string> _mark;

    public List<string> Mark
    {
        get { return _mark; }
        set { _mark = value; }
    }

    public void Get()
    {
        Mark.Add("Hello");
    }
}
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Student a = new Student();
        a.Get();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cause you haven't created an instance of the list and so the error. It should be

```
private List<string> _mark = new List<string>();
```

Your property should just return it and no setter needed

```
public List<string> Mark
{
    get { return _mark; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize `_mark`. `Mark.Add("Hello")` causes `Mark`'s getter to return `_mark`, and calling `.Add` on that null object causes an exception to be thrown.

You should do eg.

```
protected List<string> _mark = new List<string>();
```

Comment: `new List<>`?? `List<>` is an unbounded generic type and not closed

Comment: @Rahul Whoops, too much Java recently... Corrected, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "is it possible to do without writing this" (and a `new` use), the answer is no, because creating a new object might not be your intention.
Consider `bob` in the following (contrived) example:

```
  List<string> jim = new List<string>();
  List<string> bob;
  //code..
  bob = jim;
  //code...
```

A more realistic scenario might be a `List<List<string>>` where you retrieve a `List<string>` into a variable.